# Any program to combine several images into one for use with CSS and to reduce round trip count?

Tags: css, asp.net, image, visual-studio, expression-web

I'm looking at ways to reduce the quantity of Round Trips to my site for my clients.  Right now I have several images that I think should be combined into a single image like this:

http://aspnetajax.componentart.com/common/themes/20101/Office2010Silver/Static.png

and then spit out some CSS like this:

http://aspnetajax.componentart.com/common/themes/20101/Office2010Silver/theme.css

... that way I can reduce the round trips and increase the speed in which my site is used (after the first load).  Is there any simple tool that will do this for me?  I figure it's 2010 and someone somewhere automated this.  I have Visual Studio, and Expression Web and don't see it there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's this online [CSS Sprite Generator](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/) which should do what you're looking for. It will generate the image sprite from a zipped collection of single images, as well as the corresponding CSS rules to target and display each component image.

Answer (score 2):

There's [SpriteMe](http://spriteme.org/) which is the online version of the 2010 tool you're looking for.

Comment: Uploading a zip works best in my case, but this is a cool tool! +1